# Phone outline Android Studio (After update)

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-studio

Sorry in advance for the stupidity of this question, but it is wrecking my head!

Where is the little phone outline for my preview in Android Studio?

I know it's silly but it always helped me visualise what I was building and now for the life of me I can't find it. Is this part of the new update or what?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Try clicking the gear icon in the top right corner

Comment: Thanks cricket. But the gear icon is for the window pane controls only. Cant believe I still cant figure this out. Lol

Comment: Are you able to get a screenshot from somewhere to get what you are referring to?

Comment: This is similar to what it used to look like. You can see the phone outline. https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4rkn.jpg

Comment: I think you have to open the Text Tab at the bottom of that view. You are currently showing the Design tab, which essentially is the phone outline

Comment: The text tab just moves the whole thing over to the right to display the code. There is no change to the display of the phone?

Comment: Not until you add a View, no

Comment: How do you mean? what view do I need to add to get the phone there?

Comment: I think I misunderstood. You already see the phone outline. That's clearly what your picture shows. Honestly, I use Intellij, not Android Studio, and I don't think this update has been applied there yet

Comment: I don't see the phone outline? The first screenshot is what I see. The last link to a screenshot is what I used to see. They remove the outline?

Comment: Looks to me like the phone outline is full screen. Like it used to be in Eclipse. You can drag and drop views, edit their properties using the right hand side, and if you need to edit the XML directly, you use the Text tab

Comment: Where do I get the views from though? Are these something I need to import or develop or?

Comment: Open the "Pallete" panel that is against the left side of your image

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be in the Design tab. Use the Text tab instead.

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/images/write/layout-editor-text_2-2_2x.png))</sub>

[Build a UI with Layout Editor](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor.html)

If you're asking about the frame of the device, why do you need that? It just takes up space in the view. But besides, I think you can toggle that from the device drop down (where it says "Nexus 6" in your image), or at least used to be able to.

Answer (score 0):

if you were asking about the smart phones frame like the phone given below :

[image]

I couldn't find it either,i think they removed that feature,but the frame is now available only in the Virtual Device Emulator.

Comment: Yep this is exactly what I was talking about. Ya I have it in the emulator. Disappointing that they removed it from the preview. Guess I will just have to get used to it. :) (FYI, my main issue with the emulator was the time it takes to load, but found out you can add more RAM to it. Running now with 10GB instead of the default 2, and things are alot more usable).

Comment: Instead of using default emulator you can use Genymotion emulator or even your phone by enabling USB debugging and connecting it to your pc , sp when you click the run button in android studio it will show your phone, this method is the fastest.

Comment: Cheers Gatsby. Appreciate the input guys.